# Using React useRef() to apply focus to a TextArea inside a Popover when opened

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, focus

I have an AntDesign Popover that contains a TextArea.

```
<Popover trigger="click" content={footnoteContent} title="Footnote" visible={footnotePopoverVisible} onVisibleChange={handleFootnoteVisibleChange} >
  ... a custom Button...
</Popover>
```

The const used for the content is as follows:

```
  const footnoteContent = (
    <Form form={form}>
      <Form.Item name={`${cellData.key}-fn`} initialValue={initialValue}>
        <Tooltip placement="left" title="Press Ctrl + Enter to close this window.">
        <Input.TextArea
          disabled={disabled}
          bordered={false}
          autoComplete="off"
          style={{ width: "300px" }}
          autoSize={{ minRows: 4 }}
          placeholder="Enter footnote"
          onBlur={() => save(cellData.key, form.getFieldValue(`${cellData.key}-fn`))}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          autoFocus={true}
          ref={ref => { inputRef.current = ref; }}
        />
        </Tooltip>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
```

I understand there is a lot going on here. However, note that I have set autoFocus on, and as expected, the first time I open the Popover the TextArea does in fact get focus. However, any subsequent clicks to open that same Popover and the TextArea is no longer automatically getting focus. I investigated and discovered `useRef()` hooks should help.

So, near the top of my Functional Component I have declared:

```
const inputRef = useRef();
```

and note that within my TextArea I have set the ref as follows (following some examples I found online):

```
ref={ref => { inputRef.current = ref; }}
```

The popover code above has a call to a function `onVisibleChange` which points to this function:

```
  function handleFootnoteVisibleChange (visible) {
    setFootnotePopoverVisible(visible);
    if (visible) {
      if (inputRef.current) {
        console.log(inputRef.current);
        inputRef.current.focus();
      }
    }
  }
```

Which I hoped would just re-focus the text area when the popover is made visible. However, nothing seems to happen. When I inspect the session and check the `console.log(inputRef.current);` above, there seems to be a `focus()` function to call... yet nothing is happening.

[image]

Comment: Did you check these focus examples? https://ant.design/components/input/#components-input-demo-focus

Comment: If you store the Textarea's state somewhere else you could perhaps use `destroyTooltipOnHide={true}` on the `Tooltip`. This makes sures that it is recreated so that `autofocus` just works. You'd have to keep the content in `state` though, because otherwise that'll also be lost..

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, I will take a look at the examples (I hadn't seen them). However  I think my specific problem is born out of the fact that I am opening the TextArea after the initial page render via the Popover component. I will take a look in more detail when I am back at my desk though as I may be missing something. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks as well Tommos...! That is actually a great idea I think I will give it a go! Hadnt thought down that route yet! The data is stored in a state so could be a winner! Cheers for that!

Comment: Tommos, your suggestion worked a treat. I added the DestroyTooltipOnHide property then changed the supplied data as a state and re-set the state to itself on each time the popup is made visible. Seems to have done the trick! If you wanted to add an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer. If not, then I will put the answer myself in case it may help anyone else. Many thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

With `useRef`, apply the ref direct to your input field.

```js
const myRef = useRef();
...
<MyInput ref={myRef} ...
```

The method you showed is legacy `ref` assignment from class based components. `useRef` works different.

Comment: OP is able to log the element so the ref is getting assigned properly.

Comment: Good point. Still wrong form, but good point. Better option is to add the popover to DOM when 'shown' (guessing on click action), and have a `useEffect` to `focus` on mount.

Comment: Thanks for the above. Using the direct method you suggest didn't work when I tried it earlier as it seemed to only update on the initial load. As these are TextAreas within a popover that renders later, the above method I have used seems to do the trick where I see the console.log() every time I open the popover.